# How to Implement Smart Lock for Passwords to Android Application

Tags: android, google-play-services, credentials, google-smartlockpasswords

Does anyone has knowledge about Smart Lock?
How does it works?

I want to develop an application implementing Smart Lock for passwords in Android application.

I am following https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/.

I have initialized `GoogleApiClient`

```
 mCredentialsApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API)
            .build();
```

and generated instance of `Credential` as

```
 final Credential credential = new Credential.Builder(email)
            .setPassword(password)
            .build();
```

to save credentials using `Credentials API`, I used

```
Auth.CredentialsApi.save(mCredentialsClient, credential).setResultCallback(
 new ResultCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(Status status) {
      if (status.isSuccess()) {
          // Credentials were saved
      } else {
          if (status.hasResolution()) {
              // Try to resolve the save request. This will prompt the user if
              // the credential is new.
              try {
                  status.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SAVE);
              } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                  // Could not resolve the request
              }
          }
      }
  }
});
```

my `Manifest` has the permission as

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

and also added `Meta data` inside application tag as

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

after doing all in Android application, I have generated project on `Google Developer Console` and have done everything as mentioned in [this link here](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/get-started).

But when I run project, I am getting an error as:

> Could not resolve error.

Has anyone worked on Google's Smart Lock for Password on Android application?

Comment: Anyone has worked on Smart Lock, waiting for reply

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64352969/smart-lock-password-integration-at-website-and-android-app

can you please check this question?

Answer (score 7):

For me, the [Smart Lock for Passwords on Android](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/) sample project worked fine. You might want to try starting from there and see if that helps. In the sample code, save credential is implemented as:

In `onCreate`:

```
    mCredentialsApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API)
            .build();
```

...
In the `saveCredetial` method:

```
    final Credential credential = new Credential.Builder(email)
            .setPassword(password)
            .build();

    Auth.CredentialsApi.save(mCredentialsApiClient, credential).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "SAVE: OK");
                        showToast("Credential Saved");
                        hideProgress();
                    } else {
                        resolveResult(status, RC_SAVE);
                    }
                }
            });
```

...
The `resolveResult` method on the main activity:

```
private void resolveResult(Status status, int requestCode) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Resolving: " + status);
    if (status.hasResolution()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "STATUS: RESOLVING");
        try {
            status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, requestCode);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "STATUS: Failed to send resolution.", e);
            hideProgress();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "STATUS: FAIL");
        showToast("Could Not Resolve Error");
        hideProgress();
    }
}
```

Comment: I always get No available accounts error in the status

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64352969/smart-lock-password-integration-at-website-and-android-app

can you able to check this question?

Answer (score 0):

Do you handle the result in the `onActivityResult(...)` callback?

The naming is slightly confusing here. You've implemented the `onResult(Status status)` callback method but that is not all the result handling you need. If your code ever hits the `status.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SAVE);` line the result of that is not going to come to `onResult(Status status)` but rather to standard `onActivityResult(...)` callback where you need to handle it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64352969/smart-lock-password-integration-at-website-and-android-app

can you able to check this question?